# Why is $\mathbb F_2[X]/X^3$ not isomorphic to $F_2[X]/X^3+2X+1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

$F_2[X]/ \langle X^3+2X+1\rangle$ has elements $0,1,x,x^2,1+x,1+x^2,x+x^2,1+x+x^2$

So does $F_2[X]/ X^3$? Why are these rings not isomorphic to each other?

Comment: So in the first one, is there a non-zero element whose third power is $0$?

Comment: They are isomorphic as vector spaces but not as rings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one has a unique maximal ideal $(x)$. (Do you need help showing this?)

In the second one, the polynomial factors into irreducibles like this: $(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$, so there are two maximal ideals $(x-1)$ and $(x^2+x+1)$ in the ring.

---

Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, you could go on to show the second ring is isomorphic to $F_2\times F_4$, which has no nonzero nilpotent elements, whereas the first ring has a nonzero element cubing to $0$.

Comment: The polynomial is not irreducible, as it has the root $1$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Oop, I overlooked the 2 :'( Thanks, will work on it

Comment: Yeah, I think the OP might want to think a bit more about the question, since that $2$ was still there.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft That's true, maybe there is a typo. I've gone ahead and fixed the problem temporarily and I won't be sore if the question changes a bit.

Comment: I don't think we've covered maximal ideals yet, I know that $\langle X^2+2X+1\rangle$ is a principle ideal, and the elements of these factor rings are the same.

Comment: @GRS If you really want to be elementary, you can take an arbitrary nonzero element of the second ring and cube it, and show that it cannot possibly be zero. Since $x^3=0$ in the first ring, this is enough to show no isomorphism exists between the two rings.

Comment: @GRS Btw, if what you've written in the question really has no typos, then $x^3+2x+1=x^3+1$ in $F_2[x]$.

Comment: @rschwieb thanks a lot :) , I double checked there are no typos. I have to find something with the same number of elements as $\mathbb F_2[X]/\langle X^3+X^2+1\rangle$ but not isomorphic to it. I was told that that was the answer, which I didn't understand